# Unable to install ifrename on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: apt, 20.04, software-installation

I'm not able to install ifrename in Ubuntu 20.04 with `sudo apt install ifrename`. I get the following error message when trying to install ifrename.

```
$ sudo apt install ifrename
Reading package lists... Done 
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package ifrename
```

Comment: That package hasn't been used since a decade ago. Perhaps you should be asking about how to do what want - probably renaming interfaces? - instead of what you think is the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can download and install `ifrename` from [Debian *bullseye* repository](https://packages.debian.org/bullseye/ifrename) as follows:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget -c http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/w/wireless-tools/ifrename_30~pre9-13.1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./ifrename_30~pre9-13.1_amd64.deb
```

Then consult with its man-page by `man ifrename` locally or [online](https://manpages.debian.org/bullseye/ifrename/ifrename.8.en.html).